# UITableview not rotating correctly in UIPopover

Tags: ipad, ios, uipopovercontroller

I have a UITableview inside a popover. Initially the popover is displayed in portrait and upon rotation to landscape it disappears as expected. When rotated back to portrait and the popover is caused to be presented again, the tableview is shown in landscape mode inside the popover.  How can I prevent the tableview from rotating, or cause it to rotate back?

Comment: Ditto.  I'm thinking I should just dismiss any open popovers whenever I rotate, however, my view controller in the popover never receives a "willRotate..." method call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a reference to the popover in the view controller that opens it.  That view controller will receive willRotate messages.  You can dismiss the popover from there.